# Is the product of two non-holomorphic function always non-holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $h(z)$ is a complex function. I have noticed that $h(z) = f(z)\cdot g(z)$, where $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are non-holomorphic. Can $h(z)$ be holomorphic?

Can a similar statement be made, if $f(z)$ is holomorphic, but $g(z)$ is not?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, consider $\bar z \cdot \dfrac 1{\bar z} = 1$. However, if $f$ is holomorphic and $h$ is holomorphic, then $g=h/f$ is holomorphic wherever $f\ne 0$.

Comment: Well, in your example the non-holomorphic function $\overline{z}$ and its reciprocal $1/\overline{z}$ multiply to give a *holomorphic* (constant) function 1, don't they?

Comment: Right, so the product of two non-holomorphic functions *can* be holomorphic; hence my "Yes." :)

Comment: And in the case that $ \bar z ^2\cdot \bar z ^2 = \bar z ^4$?

Comment: @user_of_math The "yes" is to the question in the body, but not the title.

Comment: Good point. I rarely pay attention to titles, as they usually have little content. My apologies.

Comment: @TedShifrin very nice example!