# product of two no where differentiable is also nowhere differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

Is product of two no where differentiable functions always no where differentiable?

For example,  we have $f(z) =\overline{z} $
and $g(z) = \overline{z}^2$.

We know that $f(z)$ is no where differentiable in $\Bbb C,$
but from here we find that $g(z)$ is no where differentiable except at zero 
so in general, can we say that the product of two non differentiable functions may be differentuable at some point in $\Bbb C$ ?

I mean I'm asking, can we conclude any general result ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948421/is-the-product-of-two-non-holomorphic-function-always-non-holomorphic ?

Comment: Do the functions have to be continuous or have some other properties? If not, why not just partition the domain into two dense sets, $E$ and $F,$ and let $f(x)=1$ for all $x \in E$ and $f(x) = -1$ for all $x \in F,$ and let $g(x)=-1$ for all $x \in E$ and $g(x) = 1$ for all $x \in F?$ Then each of $f$ and $g$ is nowhere differentiable, and their product is a constant function.

Comment: Nope. $\chi_{[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}}\cdot\chi_{[0,1]\cap\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}=0.$